# md5sum mismatch when make copying the binary file

Tags: linux, cp, md5sum

I am using buildroot, it is copying custom binary from /target_skeleton/etc/ to /root/etc. Seeing md5sum mismatch, the reason behind this is, file is not copying properly. My file size is 1.4M but it copied only 44k.

Make uses "cp -af" for file copy, but it copies only the partial file.

Comment: So do you use `rsync` or `cp -af`? `cp` doesn't do partial copying. And how is the use of `make` related to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself, the binary was stripped. That why the checksum was varied.